# htaccess URL rewriting root url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/index.php?flash=1 [L,R=301]
```

1. I have a page where I want to rewrite my base url, but I have some problems. I have the above in my `.htaccess` file but still the Rewrite will not take effect or work and Rewrite to `index.php?flash=1` when users land on my page, what could the problem be? 
   In short what I want to do is that when someone lands on my page `example.com/` the url should be `example.com/index.php?flash=1`

short: i want to change my root url when someone visits my page to something else, how?

1. This also has to do with `mod_rewrite` and the above question, is it searchengine friendly? if not how can i make it ? from what i heard with the url i use above searchengines with not index anything after the questionmark, what would be your suggestion to change if i want searchengines to index my pages ?

Comment: Why would you want it to end with .php twice?  I'm not even sure that's allowed.  Re-write your question so it is more clear as to what you're trying to achieve here and why.

Comment: i just rewrite my questions :)

Comment: So you're saying that when a user goes to your site http://example.com you want it to push them to http://example.com/index.php?flash=1 ... is that correct?

Comment: See my response below in that case

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can use just a standard re-direct instead of dealing with re-writes.

place an index.html file in your root with this line in it:

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=index.php?flash=1">
```

The index.html file should be viewed before index.php would be, then it just does a redirect.

If not place `<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=index2.php?flash=1">` at the top of index.php and just make a new index2.php file to display the content you want.

It's a work around, but it's a quick fix.